# pyqtgraph histogram LUT Item - how to change color?

Tags: python, colors, histogram, pyqtgraph

I want to change the color of the blue bar in the histogram.

I've already changed the color of the background:

```
.ui.histogram.setBackground(background= pg.mkColor(37,37,37))
```

But I don´t know how to change the color of the [Blue Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iE1Xs.png).
(I imported pyqtgraph as pg)

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard for me to make a answer that I'm certain of, because I don't have all information. For instance what is `ui` in your question? Next time please make an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Anyway, assuming you have a `ImageView` object called `imgView` the following should work:

```
alpha = 50
region = imgView.histogram.item.region
region.setBrush(color=(255, 0, 0, alpha))
for line in region.lines:
    line.setPen(color=(255, 0, 0, 255))
```

Make sure that `alpha` is smaller than 128. The value of `2 * alpha` will be used when you hover above the region, and you will get a warning if it exceeds 256.

By the way, the `imgView.histogram.item` is a `HistogramLutItem`. I got my answer by looking at its [source code](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/pyqtgraph-0.10.0/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/HistogramLUTItem.py).

Comment: Well Thank you very much :)
and also thank you for the advise, will do an MVCE next time, this was my first time posting on stackoverflow so please forgive me for my mistakes ;)

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please mark the my answer as *correct* if you think it answered your question completely.